# gdb - where is function called from?

Tags: c, gdb

This seems like a simple question...
I have a library (no source code) which calls one of my own functions (`cbp_Gen`, the `fptr` is passed at some point previously).
I have a breakpoint in that function and I would like to know where in my code it's all called from.
I thought a simple `finish` would bring me back to my own code on top, but it does not work. I can `continue`, but not `finish`.

Sample debug session (slightly cleaned up):

```
(gdb) run
Starting program
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
[New Thread 0xb7f6d6d0 (LWP 1100)]

DEBUG ReadIniFile-187 Enter[New Thread 0x74cdb90 (LWP 1104)]
[New Thread 0x2886b90 (LWP 1105)]

Breakpoint 8, cbp_Gen ()
    at SomeCode.c:592
592   SetPanelAttribute(panel, ATTR_WIDTH, Width=MinWidth);

(gdb) bt
#0  cbp_Gen ()
    at SomeCode.c:592
#1  0x001d5e37 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/libcvi.so
#2  0x00000088 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000c in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000 in ?? ()

(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  cbp_Gen ()
    at SomeCode.c:592
0x001d5e37 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/libcvi.so
Value returned is $25 = 1

(gdb) finish
Run till exit from #0  0x001d5e37 in ?? () from /usr/local/lib/libcvi.so
Warning:
Cannot insert breakpoint 0.
Error accessing memory address 0x88: Input/output error.
```

Comment: Your stack appears to be corrupt, so it cannot be safely traversed back. Consider using valgrind or at least `-fstack-protector-all` gcc flag to find the cause.

Comment: I think that you can end up with strange-looking stacks in multithreaded code without corrupting your stack, which might be the case here. It would be helpful to see valgrind output, though.

Comment: My guess is that your function pointer is being called as the top-level function of a thread so there's nothing to `finish` to. Please give us the output of `info threads` during a problematic session.

Comment: @PatrickCollins unknown symbols yes, but addresses themselves are way too low (three last addresses all in lower 0x0 page - I'm not even sure you *can* mmap page to NULL).